# Is there a way to create route groups in an aspnet controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want to know if there's a way to create subclasses that act as a routing group for an api using AspNetCore Mvc.

These are the routes I need to use.

`api/speak`
`api/dance/tango`
`api/dance/salsa`
`api/sing/song`
`api/sing/tune`

```
[Route("api")]
[ApiController]
public class ApiController: Controller Base {
    private IMyService myService;
    
    public ApiController(IMyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    [Route("dance")] // This is what I want to do, create a sub-route "group"
    public class Dance {
        [HttpGet("tango")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Tango() {
            return Okay(myService.TangoDance());
        }

        [HttpGet("salsa")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Salsa() {
            return Okay(myService.alsaDance());
        }
    }

    [Route("sing")] // And create a second sub-route "group" in the controller
    public class Dance {
        [HttpGet("song")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Song() {
            return Okay(myService.SingSong());
        }

        [HttpGet("tune")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Tune() {
            return Okay(myService.SingTune());
        }
    }

    [HttpGet("speak")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Speak() {
        return Okay(myService.Words());
    }
}
```

In the code above `myService` doesn't work in the subclasses. I used that code as I felt it explained best what I want to accomplish. (I had the subclasses inherit `ApiController` so that I could use `myService` inside those methods but that didn't fix the routes not working.)

The reason I'm on stack overflow is because I can't get this to work, and I can't find anything online.

I'm using Swagger to test the routes, that's how I can see that they're not showing up.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Normally each of those classes would indeed be different classes, but they would also be Controllers in their own right i.e. `public class DanceController : Controller` and `public class SingController : Controller` and routing would "Just Work" ™

Comment: @phuzi Would that still mean I would use `[Route("api/[controller]")]` to route to those classes? My main concern is if the `api` route changes, I would need to individually edit each sub-route

Comment: To make it easier to replace `"api/[controller]"` you could define somewhere a const value like `public const string BaseUrl = "api/"`. On your controllers you write `[Route(Constants.BaseUrl + "[controller]")]` and you have only one place to change.

Comment: There are valid reasons why you may want different base routes to do with versioning but once the API is published and in use the routes should never change - to do so would break the clients using the API. Before then you could just do a quick search and replace e.g. `[Route("api/` -> `[Route("new-api-route/`

Comment: @Oliver that's like the missing key to the solution, thank you!

Comment: @phuzi you make a great point, I'm always trying to think of ways to make my code more developer friendly but I guess I shouldn't stress about it too much when it shouldn't be changing anyway. Thank you for your comments and answer!

Comment: Yeah. I know sometimes there's more actual code with essentially empty constructors but it makes everything cleaner and allows any specialised initialisation to be added later, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These would be separate controllers. There's a good argument for doing it this way (idiomatically), anyone with experience would instantly recognise the pattern and know exactly how things work.

You would use a base controller to capture the service dependency:

```
[ApiController]
public abstract class MyBaseController: ControllerBase {
    protected IMyService myService;
    
    public MyBaseController(IMyService myService) {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
}
```

And then implement the controllers like so, passing the (injected) dependency down to your base controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SpeakController: MyBaseController {
    public SpeakController(IMyService myService) : base(myService)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet] // GET api/speak
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return Okay(myService.Words());       
    }
}
```

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class DanceController: MyBaseController {
    public DanceController(IMyService myService) : base(myService)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet] // GET api/dance/tango
    public async Task<IActionResult> Tango() {
        return Okay(myService.TangoDance());
    }

    [HttpGet] // GET api/dance/salsa
    public async Task<IActionResult> Salsa() {
        return Okay(myService.alsaDance());
    }
}
```

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SingController: MyBaseController {
    public SingController(IMyService myService) : base(myService)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet] // GET api/sing/song
    public async Task<IActionResult> Song() {
        return Okay(myService.SingSong());
    }

    [HttpGet] // GET api/sing/tune
    public async Task<IActionResult> Tune() {
        return Okay(myService.SingTune());
    }
}
```